# Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0) Version not showing Spring Framework default logs in console?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, macos

I am using Eclipse IDE 2018-12 on Mac OS Mojave for project development, unfortunately unable to see default spring framework console logs in eclipse console, surprisingly i am able to see the other System.out.println statements used in project, Have anybody came across this issue or it's a bug with eclipse IDE 2018-12 ?

Comment: Do you have logback.xml file in src/main/java/resources directory in your spring project ?

Comment: No, for now I have created a simple Spring 4.2 Project, having commons-logging.jar & log4j-1.2.14.jar in my project classpath.

Comment: can you add,`import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;`  `private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(<your-class-name>.class);` and `log.info("Hello world");`, works fine for me: `21:20:44.292 [main] INFO hello.Application - Hello world`

Comment: The question is too abstract, if you can provide the link or your project, probably people will help you.

Comment: @Sambit Can I have your E-Mail id, so that I can share the zipped project structure ?

Comment: @Sambit inboxed the structure to you, please check.

Comment: Check and follow what I have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the above discussion, I provide below the way to configure your spring project. It is not maven or gradle type project. First of all you have to create a **log4j.properties** file and keep this file inside your resources folder. I provide below the sample log4j.properties file.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Make Right click on the resource folder in eclipse and click **Build Path > Use as Source Folder**

See the image below.

[image]

Finally, I have modified your HelloClient.java

Use the following line for Log4j logger.

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HelloClient.class);
```

instead of the following line

```
private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HelloClient.class);
```

Also, import the following line.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

Comment out the following lines in the code.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

Use this following line

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

in place of the following line

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/applicationContext.xml");
```

Now run the class HelloClient.java in eclipse, you can see the number logs lines in console.